# Image file management in a web service

Tags: php, image, web-services

I'm developing a web service in `php` which generates images using an external application. After generating the image file is inserted into the html page. Like this:

`<img src="img/52454879c7158.png">`

After viewing the file, it is no longer needed. But in the end in a folder with pictures accumulate a large number of files. How can I automate the deletion of files?

Comment: You should Set the CRON JOB Which will run daily and empty the given img directory if there is no other content will be received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete time just use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php%E2%80%8E)

```
unlink(folder/filename);
```

Example

```
unlink("folder/images/image_name.jpeg");
```

Show Image after delete image using php

```
$imageUrl = "/images/123.jpg"; // link to image
$imginfo = getimagesize($imageUrl); // get mime info

header("Content-type: " . $imginfo['mime']); // add Content-type header

readfile($imageUrl); // show image

unlink($imageUrl); // delete image
```

Comment: If I delete a file in the same script, a client will not have time to download it. How to set a delay for `unlink`?

Comment: image download after call one ajax and unlink that file

Comment: Check my answer fro CRONTAB

Comment: @AshwinP CRONTAB is ok but if client not download that image cron tab automaticully delete that image so what is the use

Comment: But here question is that How can we know that user has download the file or view the file for that any Session variable is managed? or in database any fields should be updated that the user has download the given file.

Comment: In simple one line you can use:

`array_map('unlink', glob("path/to/img/*"));`

Comment: @NathanSrivi I like your idea

Answer (score 1):

You should periodically delete files in a specific directory the unix program find comes to the rescue. 
In your specific case you needed to delete all the image files from a img folder that where older than 1 days.

This is the crontab entry to accomplish that:

Command is

```
crontab -l
```

Linux Crontab Format

> MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/find /yourpathto/img/ -type f -name '*.png' -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

(everything in one line)

The code runs the program `/usr/bin/find` every day at midnight `(0 0 * * *)`. 
It checks the directory called `/yourpathto/img` for everything that is a file (`-type f`), 
has a name that ends in .png (-name '*.png') and is created 1 days ago or before that (`-mtime +1`).
The command then executes rm (remove) on all those files `(-exec rm {} \;)`.

Or, You can use the `*.*` to remove all the files inside `/yourpathto/img/*.*`

after setting-up the crontab it is automatically run and remove all the files from your `/yourpathto/img/` directory.

Alternate Option to delete files:

```
function removeall()
{
    $files = glob('path/to/img/*'); // get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
      // Here you should make one condition that if user has view / download this file and remove it 
      if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
    }
}
```

Here you should apply something that if user has download file than this function will be call to remove files.

Comment: Check my answer I have added Other things.
But Can you let me know how can you check that user has download/view the file?
Is there any global variable declare or session ?

Comment: Now I do not check moment download/view the file.